# Making RadioGroup radio buttons with images in Android... How?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

Is it possible to make Radio Buttons in Android, where there are image representation to a button instead of a regular buttons? I want it to look something like that:

[image]

The cyan in the middle represents the selected button.

How can I do it?

Comment: hey, I want exact same thing, Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`RadioButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) class has a [`buttonDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonDrawable(int)) member, derived from [`CompoundButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html).

There are multiple ways you can change this drawable.

**From java:**

```
myRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(resourceId or Drawable);
```

**From xml:**

```
<RadioButton
    android:button="@drawable/yourdrawable" 
    ...
/>
```

If you just want the checked/unchecked state look differently, then

- Add a new selector xml by rightclicking your res folder -> New ->
  Android xml -> select Drawable in the upper dropdown -> choose
  selector (in eclipse)
- To setup this selector, please take a look at this [link](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-android-checkbox-and-radiobutton-custom-style)
- From now on you can set your freshly created selector to any of your
  checkboxes/radiobuttons by using its id.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked just as I wanted it!