# How to make image as a radio button in android

Tags: java, android

In my app, I want to get survey answers from the user. So, I've decided put smiley images to act as a radio buttons. Is it possible on android?

For example, I will show smiley images when user touches the image and it will be activated like a radio button. At a time, they will be allowed to only choose one. If anyone could guide me, I would appreciate it.

Example :[image: Like this]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853245/making-radiogroup-radio-buttons-with-images-in-android-how

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question has been answered before Below is from @Benito-Bertoli

[RadioButton - how to use a custom drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432553/radiobutton-how-to-use-a-custom-drawable)

Give your radiobutton a custom style:

```
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_btn_radio</item>
</style>
```

custom_btn_radio.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

   <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

   <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

   <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

Replace the drawables with your own.

Answer (score 8):

Try like this

```
  <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
```

output:(margin and pading by yourself)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I might be a bit late. Use `android:button"@btmImage link"`

```
<RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:button="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="male"
                    android:textColor="#90999d" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you just need to handle these two states, and it will work already.

```xml
<RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/paragraphRadioButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:button="@drawable/btn_paragraph"
   android:padding="14dp" />
```

`btn_paragraph.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_paragraph_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_paragraph" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think these 3rd party libraries will help you achieve this functionality.

1. [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/xiprox/SimpleRatingView)
2. [SmileBar](https://github.com/eugeneek/SmileBar)

They are pretty easy to use also.