# How to customize radio button in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, radio-button

I am creating radio button in android application but i want to make it customized. But i don't know how to do it. I want image as icon and text under the icon as in this image shown.Also i want to change the color whenever any radiobutton is selected.

[image]

This type of radio button i want. Please tell me how can i make it ?

Comment: I think you already have an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38267841/13685592

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Custom Background

```
<RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/radioButtom"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@null"
   android:button="@drawable/custom_background"
   android:checked="true"
   android:text="Your Text" />
```

Here is `Custom_background.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_regular_state_drawable"
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_selected_state_drawable"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_selected_state_drawable"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_regular_state_drawable" />
```

Referance:  You can get e better description from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163987/12676247

Comment: I have found that this solution does not work for the authors designs. Adding a button with drawable will put the drawable in front of text, not on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <RadioGroup
                            android:id="@+id/radio_group_do_you_smoke"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/transparent_drawable"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView119">

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/radio_button_yes_1"
                                style="@style/BoldTextView"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
                                android:button="@null"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:foreground="@drawable/smoke_ic"
                                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck">

                            </RadioButton>
  </RadioGroup>
```

you can use android:foreground and android:foregroundGravity="center"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQgs9.png)