# How to get the selected radio button's id when it has a drawable instead of text and no button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, radio-button

I have a radio group as you can see in the code bellow with 3 RadioButtons, my radios have an image instead of a button. So the user has to select a button by pressing one of the 3 images, and I need to check which one was selected from my Fragment.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/btnGrp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="39dp" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn1"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:padding="6dip"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn2"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6dip"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn3"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6dip"/>

    </RadioGroup>
```

This is the code related to the buttons on my fragment

```
     private RadioGroup radioGroup;
     private RadioButton radioButton;
     radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnGrp);

     int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
     radioButton = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(selectedId);
      selectedRadioId = getResources().getResourceEntryName(radioButton.getId());
```

So here selectedId has a value of -1, is this because the image doesn't really behave as a RadioButton? Otherwise what is the proper way to get the checked radio button's id in my Fragment?

---

EDITED

Someone has mentioned in another question that putting RadioGroup inside a LinearLayout causes that RadioGroup will stop managing checked states of nested buttons and suggested using drawableRight instead of drawable, but that didn't solve my issue. That is why I am wondering if there is something wrong about the way I get the id.

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266387/how-to-make-image-as-a-radio-button-in-android)  aaaand  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853245/making-radiogroup-radio-buttons-with-images-in-android-how)

Comment: You can use **setOnCheckedChangeListener**
`radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
             //do work when radioButton1 is active

            } else  if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
             //do work when radioButton2 is active
          }

        }
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

```
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
         //do work when radioButton1 is active

        } else  if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
         //do work when radioButton2 is active
      }

    }
});
```

Please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener).

Answer (score 1):

`getCheckedRadioButtonId()` method returns -1 if none of the `RadioButtons` are checked.

So you have to set one of the Radio buttons checked manually. You can do it inside xml file or Fragment. Check snippet from docummentation bellow.

```
/**
 * <p>Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group.
 * Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.</p>
 *
 * @return the unique id of the selected radio button in this group
 *
 * @see #check(int)
 * @see #clearCheck()
 *
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#RadioGroup_checkedButton
 */
@IdRes
public int getCheckedRadioButtonId() {
    return mCheckedId;
}
```

Comment: When setting one of them as checked, only that one's id gets returned no matter which other button I select

Comment: Well its because you getting id inside onCreatView. You need to set Listener for changes happening while application is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(context.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
```